# Hexo server not working

Tags: hexo

I'm installing Hexo blog.

After run npm **install hexo-server --save**,I run **Hexo server** ,and then I received"Usage: hexo

Commands:
  help     Get help on a command.
  init     Create a new Hexo folder.
  version  Display version information.

Global Options:
  --config  Specify config file instead of using _config.yml
  --cwd     Specify the CWD
  --debug   Display all verbose messages in the terminal
  --draft   Display draft posts
  --safe    Disable all plugins and scripts
  --silent  Hide output on console

For more help, you can use 'hexo help [command]' for the detailed information
or you can check the docs: http://hexo.io/docs/
"

I have checked the package.json there has  "hexo-server": "^0.2.2" in "dependencies" and there are no Plugins in _config.yml

Anybody knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done anything else than just installed Hexo as you described, then you don't have the needed Hexo folders around. Run `hexo init` first to create needed assets.

Documentation [here](https://hexo.io/docs/setup.html).

Comment: I didn't do hexo init,I will try it later.Since it didn't work.I have given up building blog by hexo.Now I'm coding a blog by myself,using vue+express+mongodb.Thank  you for your suggestion!